# How to change contrast in a popup window?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

I want to use a popup window to indicate some failure in our Addon. However i noticed that the default theme does not create enough contrast between background and text color:

[image]

I found where in the Theme settings i can modify the background color of the popup window. But i could not figure out which theme property controls the  text color.

Here is the script that i used for creating the Popup:

```
import bpy

class PopupTest(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "popup.test"
    bl_label = "Popup Test"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        width = 400 * bpy.context.user_preferences.system.pixel_size
        status = context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self,
                 width=width)
        return status

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box   = layout.box()         
        box.label(text="title")
        col = box.column(align=True)
        col.label("Rig version    : 1.0")
        col.separator()
        col.label("Press the OK Button below to update")
        col.label("click anywhere outside this box to Skip")
        col.separator()
        col.label("CAUTION: ...")

    def execute(self, context):

        ob = context.object
        return {'FINISHED'}

class PanelPopupTest(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type  = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_label       = "PopupTestPanel"
    bl_idname      = "popup.testpannel"
    bl_options     = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    bl_category    = "Tools"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box   = layout.box()         
        box.label(text="title")
        col = box.column(align=True)
        col.operator("popup.test")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelPopupTest)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PopupTest)
```

Comment: How attached are you to having the box() in the popup layout? `box = layout` will give you white on black (default)

Comment: yes, that looks like a good workaround to avoid the problem. I meanwhile found that the text color is taken from the definition in Menu Back:Text. Now i wonder why it is not taken from Box:Text ...

Comment: This has been identified as a bug. here is the bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T48241

Comment: Excellent, I do like the box.